# Split line of text at pre-defined markers

Tags: excel, notepad++, multiple-columns

I apologize if this has been done but I'm up to two days of searching now for what i'd hoped would be a simple solution without success

I have a file that has 100 rows of data in it.

Each row has 380 characters.

I have a guide that tells me:

> starting at character 1, for 3 characters is information x
>
> starting at character 4, for 8 characters is information y
>
> starting at character 12, for 16 characters is information z
>
> etc

For what is effectively 43 columns of information jammed into one block. Some information is names, dates, numbers that have 2 decimal places, numbers that have 8 decimal places etc.

E.G.

```
MJBN1XXXXXX00018YNN1C11010C  SMITH JOHNNE    99999N     20140306E 201403112014030667011M107V 10000000000000        0000000000018000000C  000000755000000 0000001359000 Y0000000002500 0000000000000 0000000000000 0000000000000 0000000000000 0000000000000 0000000000000 0000001361500 NOVX21 INC CL B               0201403060001810
```

I'm trying to use something mainstream, e.g. Excel or notepad++ to split each of the 100 rows out to columns, even if it's by inserting a "," at each break so I can open it in excel.

I'm aware I can do this via excel "text to columns" function by dragging the column splitter to the place it's needed but I'm looking for a repeatable process, there are about 10 files of varying widths that come in daily and they could be 10k+ rows at a time but if i could build a macro or script for each of the 10 file types that I can run on demand when I open a fresh file that would be my ultimate goal.

Comment: Just take your idea to the next level - Record an Excel macro that opens the text file and places the column-breaks where you want them - Once you have that, you can change just a few lines of code to make it a repeatable process / do that for every file in a directory, etc....

Answer (score 1):

It may be time to learn some scripting, my friend.

You can possibly use Excel's "text to columns" and specify a delimiter if there is a consistent one (e.g. tab or spaces), but that may trip up if someone has a middle name, or other wrinkles arise.

If there's a complex but somewhat consistent delimiter, you can use [regular expressions](http://qntm.org/files/re/re.html) to find/replace all delimiters into tabs and import directly into Excel that way. I'm not sure if notepad++ offers this, but you can get an eval copy of [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) which does, and I highly recommend that anyways.

If you have a say in how these files are made, requesting them in a standard format like CSV will give you a lot more parsing options.

If neither of those are possible, then it's probably time to learn a little Python or Ruby. A simple 10-line script that you write once could transform these files into Excel readable in milliseconds.

I know that's not a trivial answer, but learning a programming language will change your life.

Comment: Notepad++ 6.0 or newer supports PCRE.